# Space before footnote symbol

Tags: footnotes

I have defined a new command to change the footnote symbol to an asterisk to be used on a chapter's title:

```
% New command for chapter title footnote. This command changes the
% footnote symbol from a number to an asterisk
\newcommand{\chfootnote}[1]{
\let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnote{#1}
\let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote
}
```

But when I use it I end up having a space right before the asterisk (see image below). The space does not appear if I use a regular footnote. What am I doing wrong?

```
\chapter[test]{Title\chfootnote{This is a footnote.}}
```

[image]

EDIT: Thank you all for the quick response. Here is the new code that does not add whitespace before the symbol.

```
% New command for chapter title footnote. This command changes the
% footnote symbol from a number to an asterisk
\newcommand{\chfootnote}[1]{%
\let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote
\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
\footnote{#1}
\let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote
}
```

Comment: There are three white space characters at last.`\newcommand{\chfootnote}[1]{%` will remove the first one -- the newline after `\newcommand{\chfootnote}{` introduces one spurious white space, the next one appears after `\setcounter{footnote}{0}`

Comment: As Christian explains, new lines are considered as spaces. See  [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/82917) for details.

Comment: @campa: I see three -- the `\let...` should not give rise to a spurious space, should it?

Comment: Just in case of using this macro without the optional argument of `\chapter` you need `\protect\chfootnote` in order to make this compilable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My bad (that's why I edited the comment). I meant that there is a further one after `\footnote{#1}`, but that's of course not visible in the MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I appreciate it. I have edited the question with the new version of the \chfootnote command.

Comment: your new version is still adding space `\footnote{#1}SPACE`

Comment: @campa: Well, the space *after* the footnote marker should be no issue as long as there is no content after the marker -- you're right of course with 4 spaces, I did not take that space into account because of the final spacing being of marginal importance ... in this case I am right. In average, there are 3.5 spaces ;-)